# Не работает Woocommerce Api + next.js

Tags: node.js, woocommerce

хочу реализовать интернет магазин на связке Woocommerce + Next.js.
Нашел пример работы данной связки, но он либо устарел, либо я что-то делаю не так.

Вот файл server.js:

```
const WooCommerceRestApi = require("@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api").default;
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const wooConfig = require( './woocommerceApi' );


const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();
const server = express();


const WooCommerce = new WooCommerceRestApi({
    url: wooConfig.siteUrl, // Your store URL
    consumerKey: wooConfig.consumerKey, // Your consumer key
    consumerSecret: wooConfig.consumerSecret, // Your consumer secret
    version: 'wc/v3' // WooCommerce WP REST API version
});

app.prepare()
    .then(() => {

        server.get("/products", (req, res) => {
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');
            res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

            WooCommerce.get("products").then((res)=>{
                console.log(res)
            })
        });

        server.get("/", (req, res) => {
            return handle(req, res)
        })



        server.all("*", (req,res) => {
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
            return handle(req, res)
        })

        server.listen(port, err => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.error(`> Ready on http://localhost:${port}`);
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.error(err.stack);
        process.exit(1);
    });
```

На самом сайте после следующего запроса:

```
const clientConfig = {
    siteUrl: 'http://coffee'
};
var res = await fetch( `${clientConfig.siteUrl}/products` )
```

Получаю ошибку 404

Если же запустить файл server.js через node, получается получить данные

Изначально Wordpress стоял в папке с проектом next, но это ничего не меняет.

Если у кого-то есть предположения или идеи как можно исправить ситуацию, или имеется материал по данному вопросу, с радостью выслушаю.

```
node v10.16.0
wp 5.2.2
woocommerce 3.6.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Что-то делаете не так, а именно... Согласно [документации](https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/?javascript#libraries-and-tools), импорт через `require` должен выглядеть следующим образом:

```
const WooCommerceRestApi = require("@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api").default;
```

В отличии от Вашего кода - добавилось `.default`, чего у Вас нет, отсюда и ошибка. Однако импорт через конструкцию `import` (ES6) выглядит следующим образом:

```
import WooCommerceRestApi from "@woocommerce/woocommerce-rest-api";
```

После этого следующая конструкция кода заработает успешно:

```
const WooCommerce = new WooCommerceRestApi({
  url: 'http://example.com', // Your store URL
  consumerKey: 'consumer_key', // Your consumer key
  consumerSecret: 'consumer_secret', // Your consumer secret
  version: 'wc/v3' // WooCommerce WP REST API version
});
```

> Код ответа ошибки [HTTP 404 Not Found](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404) указывает, что сервер не
>   может найти запрошенный ресурс. Этот код ответа, вероятно, является
>   самым известным из-за его частотности в сети, и его часто называют
>   сломанным ресурсом или мертвой связью.

Не найден запрашиваемый ресурс - проверьте правильность указанного URL, убедитесь что порты не закрыты и указаны верно, проверьте фаервол, не блокируются ли запросы.

Comment: Сделал как Вы сказали, и единственный результат - получение данных через консоль Node. На самом сервере после билда я все также получаю 404.

Comment: Исправил ошибки, все еще жду помощи(